# How to remove numbers in string containing a specific identifier with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm stuck and hoping one of you regex wizards has insight. I need to remove anything in a string that contains "PK##.##". So for example:

```
string ts = "HELLO PK 2233.33 TEST PK11.1";
//Should output as "HELLO PK 2233.33 TEST"

string ns = Regex.Replace(ts, @"PK[\d]", string.Empty); 
//currently outputting "HELLO PK 2233.33 TEST 1.1"
```

My current Regex almost works, but only removes 1 digit from the "PK" part of the string.

Comment: Try `\s+PK\d+(?:\.\d+)?` instead.

Comment: Try `PK\d+\.\d+`

Comment: WORKS! You regex wizards never cease to amaze. Please post as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: Use `\bPK\d*\.?\d+`

Answer (score 2):

You need to match trailing whitespaces and fractional part as well:

```
\s+PK\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

If `\.\d+` part is mandatory remove the enclosing parentheses:

```
\s+PK\d+\.\d+
```